# Implementing a 3D Tag Cloud in ReactJS

Tags: jquery, reactjs, animation, components, cloud

[image]

I know this can be easily done using jquery 3d tag cloud plugin in plain Javascript. But can someone tell me how to create this without jquery (or how to integrate the jquery in a particular react component)

Answer (score 1):

Hey I was looking for an answer to this too

What I did was

```
npm install jquery
```

Download the plugin and extracted the jquery.svg3dtagcloud.js file

**React Component**

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import './jquery.svg3dtagcloud'
class Box extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
    const settings ={

   
    }
  this.$el = $(this.el);
  this.$el.svg3DTagCloud(settings)
}
  
render() {
  return (
    <div id="tagcloud" ref={el => this.el = el}></div>
    );
}
```

**Hooks**

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import './jquery.svg3dtagcloud'
export default function Skills() {
    const settings = {
            

    }

    const svgEl = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        const $svgEl = $(svgEl.current)
        $svgEl.svg3DTagCloud(settings)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div id="tagcloud" ref={svgEl}></div>
    );

}
```

Comment: And how using a hook ?

Comment: @VincentDucroquet updated with hooks

Comment: @EricLiao I tried this but i kept getting import errors from import './jquery.svg3dtagcloud'

Comment: @worknovel sorry forgot to mention you also need to add 'import jQuery from 'jquery';' to the jquery.svg3dtagcloud.js file, if you look at the bottom you should see an if statement for it